# How to count number of repeated/empty items in array using *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor

As an example, some of them don't have colour:

```
items = [
       {
        messageTagId: "1",
        description: "Test Tag1"

       }, 
       {
        messageTagId: "2",
        description: "Test Tag1",
        tagColor: "#ff0000"
       }, 
       {
        messageTagId: "3",
        description: "Test Tag1"

       }, 
       {
        messageTagId: "4",
        description: "Test Tag1",
        tagColor: "#ff0000"
       }, 
       {
        messageTagId: "5",
        description: "Test Tag1",
        tagColor: "#ff0000"
       }, 
        ]
```

to display: should count the ones without colour at all, and with colour property

```
  [2] [3]
```

where 2 without color and 3 with color

this is my *ngFor loop, but its not correct this should create one span with [2], and second span with [3]

```
  <span *ngFor="let messageTag of items" >{{items.length}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I need filter first;

On your Component do this:

```
const newItems = items.filter(item => !item.color)
```

On your HTML do this:

```
<span *ngFor="let messageTag of newItems" >{{messageTag.messageTagId}}</span>
```